# Solr Search text with underscore (_)

Tags: solr, full-text-search

How to search text containing underscore(_) in [solr](/questions/tagged/solr). Eg: This_is_for_testing". I want to search for "testing".

Answer (score 2):

I assume this_is_for_testing is your indexed text?

The StandardTokenizerFilterFactory doesn't tokenize on underscores. You will need to use the PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory to transform underscores into spaces then tokenize the text.

see: [PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.html)

```
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="_"
     replacement=" " replace="all" />
```

so the indexing will be

1. this_is_for_testing
2. this is for testing
3. this | is | for | testing

You only need to do this on the analysis side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory for this job.

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1"
            generateNumberParts="1" catenateNumbers="0" splitOnNumerics="1"
            catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"
            stemEnglishPossessive="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

[image]